# Ubuntu Studio: Record from multiple remote locations (give applications Jack audio plugs?)

Tags: ubuntu-studio, jack

I am an intermediate Linux user but new to Ubuntu Studio and Jack Audio.

I use Ubuntu Studio to make a weekly podcast. My co-host in in other part of the world and we converse over Discord. I use Ardour to record the show. In Ardour I use two channels/tracks. One is for the local feed, my, microphone. The other is the remote, co-hosts, microphone. Using Carla to route my microphone into Ardour is easy enough. (System Capture 1 to Ardour's created "Local" track.) In order to get my co-hosts audio feed into Ardour I currently route the entire pulse audio output into the a separate track, titled "remote", in Ardour using Carla. This works alright but all the systems application noises would be recorded to to the "remote" track. Also it means that if I have a guest on the show other then my co-host they would both get recorded to the same track making editing a nightmare.

What I would like would be if there was a plug in the Carla Patch-bay for Discord or any other voice chat program that I could use. This way I could have one track for local, one from pulse audio, and one from a voice chat application.

Other configuration to the same ends welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here may be jack sinks.

These create interfaces between jack and pulse. Let's say you wanted to record the audio from a youtube video.

1. Start Jack
2. Make your sinks (see below)
3. Open Ardour
4. Create a new stereo track
5. Right click on it to get the popup menu and select "inputs..."
6. There's a list of tabs along the right. Click on other.
7. Find your sink
8. Click on the right and left in the grid so as to send them to ardour (and unclick the hardware)
9. Cue the youtube video
10. Open pulse audio volume control
11. Go to the playback tab
12. Your webrowser and the YT video will be on the list.
13. There's a drop down menu on the right. Select your sink. (The **same one** as in step 8)

The video audio is now routed to ardour. The steps for discord should be nearly identical (but starting with youtube allows you to try this without anyone else around).

For other jack applications, you can also connect them together or to the sinks by using the graph window in qjackctl.

To create a sink, after jack starts, run the following commands:

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink channels=2; 
pactl load-module module-jack-source channels=2; 
pacmd set-default-sink jack_out; 
pacmd set-default-source jack_in
```

You can create extra sinks or sources by adding lines:

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink sink_name=Discord-output client_name=Discord-output;
pactl load-module module-jack-source source_name=Discord-input client_name=Discord_input;
```

You can see the results of these commands in qjackctl's graph view. You can also run them automatically when you start jack via qjackctl. Click the setup button, then the options tab and paste it in to the Execute script after startup line.